General equation to calculate time required to travel a distance given initial speed and constant acceleration
I need to know the time $t$ it takes for a ship to travel a given distance $d$, with an initial speed $V_i$ and a constant acceleration $a$.
This post seems to give an answer by deriving the quadratic equation from this formula : $$d=V_i t+\frac 12at^2$$. If I'm not mistaken, the derived formula is then
$$t = \frac{-2V_i \pm \sqrt{(2V_i)^2 - 8ad} }{2a}$$
How can it be the correct formula if it cannot give an answer for a null acceleration? In case of a null acceleration, it should fall back to the formula with constant speed $t = d/V_i$ , right? Also if the acceleration is infinitesimal, the results become weird.
What am I doing wrong?

$t=V_i\frac{\sqrt{1\color{red}+2ad/V_i^2}-1}a\approx V_i\frac{ad/V_i^2}a=\frac d{V_i}$.

The formula you said:
$$t=\frac{-2V_i\pm\sqrt{4V_i^2-8ad}}{2a}$$
is wrong with the correct one being:
$$t=\frac{-2V_i\pm\sqrt{4V_i^2+8ad}}{2a}$$
gives us a quadratic solution of $t$. And moreover, if $a=0$, which represents null acceleration, the equation for $t$ is no more quadratic, so how do you expect to find the value of $t$ using the solution that solves $t$ for quadratic equation?
Moreover, in case the acceleration is too small, or negligible, then we can consider a different case:
$$t=2V_i\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+\frac{2ad}{V_i^2}}}{2a}\right)$$
Since $a$ is small, which means $a\rightarrow0$, then the term $1+\frac{2ad}{V_i^2}$ evaluates to $1$ almost, which is a mere approximation [applying Taylor's Series] which means:
$$\left(1+\frac{2ad}{V_i^2}\right)^{\frac 12}=1+\frac{ad}{V_i^2}+\cdots$$
The results lead to:
$$t\approx\frac{V_i}{a}\left(-1\pm\left(1+\frac{ad}{V_i^2}\right)\right)$$
Avoiding all other higher-power terms. This result gives us
$$t\approx\frac{V_i}{a}\left(-2-\frac{ad}{V_i^2}\right)$$
where it may lead to another solution like:
$$t\approx\frac{V_i}{a}\left(\frac{ad}{V_i^2}\right)=\frac d{V_i}$$
Consider the one, that suites your need and has a better physical significance.

As commented 1 hour ago, $$t=V_i\frac{\sqrt{1\color{red}+2ad/V_i^2}-1}a\sim V_i\frac{ad/V_i^2}a=\frac d{V_i}$$ as $a\to0$.

I think the idea of using "the" quadratic formula is that if the acceleration were zero then you would have easily solved the problem already before looking at the hint to use the quadratic formula.
But there is also an alternative quadratic formula: if $at^2 + bx + c = 0$ then
$$ t = \dfrac{2c}{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}}. $$
Applying this to the problem $at^2 + 2V_i t - 2d = 0,$ we have
$$ t = \dfrac{-4d}{-2V_i \pm \sqrt{4V_i^2 + 8ad}}
= \dfrac{2d}{V_i \mp \sqrt{V_i^2 + 2ad}}. $$
In the case where $a = 0$, taking $\mp$ as $-$ gives an undefined result but taking $+$ the formula simplifies directly to $d/V_i$, as it should, with no limits or approximations required.
The other case where this formula gives an undefined result is when $d=0$,
but again taking $\mp$ as $+$ the value is defined and simplifies to $0$.
